# How to debug Keras in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

Actually, I find the problem already in TensorFlow 1.13.0. (tensorflow1.12.0 works well).

My code is listed as a simple example:

```
def Lambda layer(temp):
    print(temp)
    return temp
```

which is used as a lambda layer in my Keras model.
In tensorflow1.12.0, the `print(temp)` can output the detail data like following

```
[<tf.Tensor: id=250, shape=(1024, 2, 32), dtype=complex64, numpy=
array([[[ 7.68014073e-01+0.95353246j,  7.01403618e-01+0.64385843j,
          8.30483198e-01+1.0340731j , ..., -8.88018191e-01+0.4751519j ,
         -1.20197642e+00+0.6313924j , -1.03787208e+00+0.22964947j],
        [-7.94382274e-01+0.56390345j, -4.73938555e-01+0.55901265j,
         -8.73749971e-01+0.67095983j, ..., -5.81580341e-01-0.91620034j,
         -7.04443693e-01-1.2709806j , -3.23135853e-01-1.0887597j ]],
```

It is because I use the 1024 as batch_size. But when I update to tensorflow1.13.0 or TensorFlow 2.0, the same code's output

```
Tensor("lambda_1/truediv:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
```

This is terrible since I can not know the exact mistakes. 
So, any idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see that output because the Keras model is being converted to its graph representation, and thus `print` printes the `tf.Tensor` graph description.

To see the content of a `tf.Tensor` when using Tensorflow 2.0 you should use `tf.print` instead of `print` since the former gets converted to its graph representation while the latter doesn't.

Comment: thank you for your kind response. It works！ however， it is really complex to debug by adding a lot of tf.print to check variables.  In tensorflow 1.12.0， I can debug with a break point within the lambda layer， and the program will stop there. However，in 2.0 the program will not stop in the lambda layer after the training begin， so I cannot easliy debug （as my custom loss function is complicated，I really need to check many variables to ensure my function is right）Do you have any idea？

Comment: When the source code gets converted into a Graph there are few things you can do to easily debug. Probably the best thing you can do is to first write the model using keras + manually writing the training loop using tf.GradienTape and all the eager stuff. In this way, you can use a debugger and debug easily. Then, if you want you can throw away the custom training loop and use Keras (or better, just decorate the training loop with @tf.function and convert the loop to a graph to speed it up)

Comment: thank you， maybe it's the best solution so far. I really like the debug way in tf 1.12.0 and a little disappointed its absence in tf 2.0. Hopefully there will be more convenient debug method in the future

Comment: Just go pure eager (the custom training loop with the tape is really powerful) and then convert to a graph. You'll get the best from both worlds, trust me :) however since this answer solved your question please remember to mark it as accepted!